# ¿Cómo hago para que las respuestas no me salgan con tuplas?

Tags: python, windows, imagen, archivo, bucles

```
 print(f"Los clientes que hay son los siguientes {listaClientes}")
```

Al momento de escribir eso para que un supuesto cliente vea que clientes existen uno espera ver algo asi como un nombre, ejemplo `Guillermo Domínguez` 
pero al ejecutar el código sale en tuplas `Los clientes que hay son los siguientes [('Guillermo', 'Dominguez')]` como hago para que no me salgan asi?

Comment: Cuando imprimo una tupla espero ver una tupla, no otra cosa.

Answer (score 2):

Existe la función `join`, esto lo que te hace es convertir un  `array`
en texto

```
'{{st_a_concatenar}}'.join(nombre_arreglo)
```

Esto quedaría algo así

```
frutas = ['pera', 'manzana', 'platano']
f"Las frutas son: {(','.join(frutas)}"
# Imprime -> Las frutas son: pera, manzana, platano
f"The fruits are: {(' and '.join(frutas)}"
# Imprime -> The fruit are: pera and manzana and platano
```

Tu problema es que tu `list` es de `tuple`, para eso primero tendrías que usar la misma función para convertirlos a `str`

```
listaClientes = [('Guillermo', 'Dominguez'), ('Pedro', 'Perez')]
listaClientesConcatenada = [' '.join(cliente) for cliente in listaClientes]
# listaClientesConcatenada es: ['Gullermo Dominguez', 'Pedro Perez']

print(f"Los clientes que hay son los siguientes {','.join(listaClientesConcatenada)}")
```